# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget

Tags: java, android, android-layout, casting

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> { // <-- line 9
private String[] mDataset;


public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView textView;
    public MyViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mTextView);
        this.textView = textView;
    }
}


public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}


@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                 int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    TextView v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false); // <-- line 36

    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    holder.textView.setText(mDataset[position]);

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}
```

}

this is the code of MyAdapter class and when i run it, The app keeps shut down so i have checked Logcat and it says

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.t5online.chat.hanbattalk, PID: 593
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
        at com.t5online.chat.hanbattalk.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:36)
        at com.t5online.chat.hanbattalk.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:9)
```

However, I can't find what the problem is in line 36 and 9.

Answer (score 1):

You are not inflating view properly in `onCreateViewHolder` . It should be something like this ,

```
 View view;
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
 view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_text_view,parent,false);
 return new MyAdapter.MyViewHolder(view);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and it worked! helped me lots.